# Get vertex coordinates of model mesh in every frame of animation

Tags: modeling, python, animation, vertices, coordinates

I am trying to get the coordinates of all vertices of a model for each frame of an animation in Blender using python. I have seen a lot of answers from 50 years ago like [Iterating vertex of every frame in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68406/iterating-vertex-of-every-frame-in-blender) that don't work and give me the same coordinates in every frame. This looked like a trivial thing that should be accessed by a simple function call or a field, I don't understand why it was like this.

```
obj = bpy.data.objects[0]
sce = bpy.context.scene


for f in range(sce.frame_start, 250 + 1):
    sce.frame_set(f)
    m = []
    for o in obj[2:]:
        o1 = o.to_mesh(preserve_all_data_layers=True) 
        m.extend([o.matrix_world @ v.co for v in o1.vertices])
    outputs.append(m)
```

In the other post I included, they say that you have to create a mesh for every frame. Although the arguments from their example don't work anymore. The models I use are from Mixamo that have different meshes for different body parts so I had to also iterate over the child objects to get all points of my mesh. The code above results the same points for every frame.

Comment: Hello ! Would you mind sharing the script you arrived to and how it doesn't work ?

Comment: @Gorgious I updated my post but it is basically the same as the link I have there.